# React/Redux: Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.AddToCart is not a function .. I keep getting this error, but I don't know what's wrong

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am simply trying to call AddToCart on each item in the list when the onclick handler is triggered, which simply decreases the item's quantity by 1 unit. Here is the relevant code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { AddToCart } from '../actions/add_to_cart';

class ItemList extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ol>
          {this.props.itemList.map((item) =>
          <li key={item.id} >
            name: {item.name} ||
            price: ${item.price} ||
            Quantity: {item.quantity}
            <button
              onClick={() => this.props.AddToCart(item.id)}
              >Add To Cart
            </button>
          </li>
        )}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ AddToCart }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { itemList: state.itemList }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ItemList);
```

This is the Action Creator:

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART';


export function addToCart(id) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    id
  };
}
```

This is the reducer:

```
import { ADD_TO_LIST } from '../actions/add_to_list';
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../actions/add_to_cart';



export default function (state = [], action) {
  console.log('action recieved', action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_LIST:
      console.log(state)
      return [
        ...state,
        { id: action.id, name: action.name, price: action.price, quantity: 10 }
  ]
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return state.map((item) => {
        if(item.id === action.id){
          // return {...state, quantity: 0}
          return Object.assign({}, item, {quantity: item.quantity - 1})
        }
        return item
      })
    }
  return state;
  console.log(state);
}
```

Been stuck on this for longer than I'de like to share. Any HELP PLEASE!!

Comment: It should be just `onClick={AddToCart.addToCart}`

Comment: Your import is incorrect. You are exporting a function called `addToCart` in your action creator but trying to import a function called `AddToCart` in your component. Easy thing to mix up, eslint has a plugin that will catch this for you. It is described in the following issue: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6541

Answer (score 3):

You are importing AddToCart:

```
import { AddToCart } from '../actions/add_to_cart';
```

but your function's name is addToCart in you action creator. It must be:

```
import { addToCart } from '../actions/add_to_cart';
```